# R: find specific element in list of data frames and assign it to colname and switch element to the right

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Let's have a list of data frames.

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1=c("a", "b", "c"),V2=c("d", "e","f"), V3=c("g","h","i"),V4=c("j","k","l"))
df2 <- data.frame(V1=c("m","n"), V2=c("o","p"), V3=c("q","r"))
l <-list(df1, df2)
> l
[[1]]
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  a  d  g  j
2  b  e  h  k
3  c  f  i  l

[[2]]
  V1 V2 V3
1  m  o  q
2  n  p  r
```

In this list there is a data frame which is turned and colnames are as element of the list. Data frame `[[1]]` just turned and merged data frames (See the picture).
[image]
  For instance column V1 and V3 cointain colnames, while V2 and V4 are variables.

I would like to run some code which match one of the elements from data frames (`ele` is a vector containing names of the primal column):

```
ele <- c("a","b","c","g","h","i")
```

and when it matches it assigns this element as a colname and assign the element in the right as a variable to this column and finally we can get new data frame, for instance:

```
dfa<-data.frame(a="d")
> dfa
  a
1 d
```

Important: note that `list[[2]]` will not be matched. I would rather opt for method for loop / lappy and get separated data frames like `dfa`, `dfb`, `dfc`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
df1[]=apply(df1,2,as.character)

setNames(as.data.frame(t(unlist(df1[,c(FALSE,TRUE)]))),
         unlist(df1[,c(TRUE,FALSE)]))

  a b c g h i
1 d e f j k l
```

We first change `factors` to `character` as `factors` don't play well in data manipulation. We then use `c(FALSE,TRUE)` to select even columns, which are the content of the `dataframe` and assign the names, which are the odds (`c(TRUE,FALSE)`)

**edit**

Checking for a match between the name-reference to carry out the process.

```
ele <- c("a","b","c","g","h","i")

l = lapply(l, function(x){
  x[]=apply(x,2,as.character)

  if (any(unlist(x)%in%ele)){
    setNames(as.data.frame(t(unlist(x[,c(FALSE,TRUE)]))),
            unlist(x[,c(TRUE,FALSE)]))
  } else {NA}
})

l

[[1]]
  a b c g h i
1 d e f j k l

[[2]]
NULL
```

If you want to delete `nulls` use `l[lengths(l) != 0]`

Comment: I am looking something like: for loop (i in 1:lenght(list)){conditions} --> output small data frames like dfa. I have multiple lists this kind so then I can bind the outcome into big data.frame. I do not know the names of the data.frames in the real list which I used to work.

Comment: For multiple dataframes, you can use `lapply(list, function(x) {...}`. In the `...` you have to put the two lines of code above changing `df1` for `x`. Still, I don't understand how the second `df` in your example can have 3 columns, if there should be names and content.

Comment: I have not stated that only part of the data frames in the list match this condition. Some of them does not contain the any colnames in the matrix. I just want to omit these data frame like df2

Comment: Moreover I got the error: "Error in names(object) <- nm : 
  'names' attribute [6] must be the same length as the vector [2]"

Comment: @Mikołaj I updated the answer... I don't know how you get the error if you run it as I wrote it.

Comment: I works on the given example. However when I was trying do reproduce this code in another list I have got the same error.